# Replace each node in binary tree with the sum of its inorder predecessor and successor

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve this problem without using an array:

```
Node replaceWithSum(Node root) {
   if (root == null) {
      return null;
   }

   Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList();
   q.add(root);

   Node predecessor, successor = null;
   while(!q.isEmpty()) {
      Node node = q.peek();
      q.remove();

      predecessor = node.left; //possible predecessor
      successor = node.right; //possible successor

      while (predecessor != null && predecessor.right != null) {
           predecessor = predecessor.right;
      }

      while (successor != null && successor.left != null) {
           successor = successor.left;
      }

      node.data = ((predecessor != null)? predecessor.data : 0) + ((successor != null)? 
                                                                   successor.data : 0)


      if (node.left != null) {
         q.add(node.left)
      } 
      if (node.right != null) {
         q.add(node.right)
      }
   }

   return root;
}
```

Using queue to traverse in level order. I understand space complexity is O(n). Could you please help me understand time complexity of this problem? If tree is skewed, worst case would be possible when we find predecessor/successor only for one node. So worst case for this problem, is when tree is balanced, so is time complexity O(nlogn)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `while (predecessor != null && predecessor.right != null) {
           predecessor = predecessor.right;
      }` Why are you doing this? If you do this it is not `O(n)`.

Comment: This is to find predecessor of that particular node.

Comment: Does this have any alternative solution without storing elements in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is `O(n)`. It's kind of like building a heap.

Suppose you have a full binary tree with height `h`.

You travel from the root to the leaves, suppose `k` is the level, it goes from `0` to `h-1`.

At level `k`, you have `2^k` nodes. For each node, it at most needs to visit `h-k` node to find its predecessor and successor.

By [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%3D0..h-1%2C+%28h-k%29*2%5Ek%29), we could get this formula:

[image]

Obviously, it's equal to `O(n)`.

Comment: thanks for your help. In case if tree is skewed, what will be time complexity?

Comment: it'll be O(n) because you have go over every node in tree